# Mono Assembly unresolved

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono

We copy all our compiled assemblies into one output folder in the postbuild step (d:\c\bin\assemblies). Using windows and the Microsoft .NET framework references to assemblies in this directory are found at compile time using a Registry entry pointing to exact that output folder:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx\OutputFolder1]
@="d:\\c\\bin\\assemblies"
```

Using Windows and Mono I succeeded by setting the environment variable ReferencePath before running xbuild.

```
SET ReferencePath=d:\c\bin\assemblies\
```

Anyway. This does not work under linux. It seems to me that the ReferencePath variable not evaluated. Can anybody shed some light on how I can set a path for Mono to look for assemblies at compiletime for linux?

Answer (score 1):

From [Assemblies and the GAC](http://www.mono-project.com/Assemblies_and_the_GAC):

> At run time, Mono looks in three places for assemblies necessary to run a program. It first searches the location of the executing assembly.
>
> ...[cut]
>
> If a required assembly isn't found there, Mono searches the MONO_PATH environment variable
>
> ...[cut]
>
> To set this variable in Linux, if you use the bash shell, type:
>
> export MONO_PATH=/path/to/assemblies:/another/path/to/assemblies
>
> Lastly, if an assembly was still not found, Mono searches the the Global Assembly Cache (GAC), a repository of shared assemblies

Comment: I have read about the MONO_PATH variable. It seems to be used only at runtime but not at compile time.

Comment: @mklein you're right...actually question concerns "compile time". I do not know xbuild, but using the mcs compiler would write something like:
'mcs -lib:/path/to/assemblies...'